# Unable to kill a process in C#?

Tags: c#, roblox

I'm currently developing a program that can inject Lua Scripts into Roblox (yes I know), everything is working fine so far, except the kill process. 
As Roblox works as a single process, I don't need to kill the tree. I have done a bit of research regarding the topic and none of them work.

Roblox runs as a process called RobloxPlayer.exe, I believe that the `Process.GetProcessesByName` should fetch the process via the name of it. Being Roblox, not RobloxPlayer.exe

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("Roblox");
foreach (Process process in processes)
{
    process.Kill();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: "I believe that the Process.GetProcessesByName should fetch the process via the name of it. Being Roblox, not RobloxPlayer.exe" Why  do you think this? Have you tried to see what happens when you use `GetProcessByName("RobloxPlayer")`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although that doesn't work.

Comment: can I have the code of the script?

Comment: @jwu I'll GitHub it on release, it doesn't have many features right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do string matching of all processes and terminate any process that matches your criteria.

```
String findThisProcess = "Roblox";

foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses()) //provides you with a list of all running processes
{
    try
    {           
        if (process.ProcessName.Contains(findThisProcess, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Process: {Path.GetFileName(process.MainModule.FileName)}, Name: {process.ProcessName}");
            process.Kill();
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Couldn't terminate process: " + ex);
    }
}
```

Edit: Added `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` so that it matches processes, regardless of their case. Eg. `VsDebugConsole.exe` will be matched even if you input `vsdebug`.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. Didn't realise that this was a viable fix.
Done!

Answer (score 0):

Get the name of current process in a variable.

```
var appName = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
var isInstanceAlready = Process.GetProcessesByName(appName.ProcessName).Where(p => p.Id != appName.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: "*I believe that the `Process.GetProcessesByName` should fetch the process via the name of it. Being **Roblox**, not **RobloxPlayer.exe***"

Comment: Yes, but you're providing a solution that wasn't related to the question. you could change your p.Id to check the name instead, and you have a valid answer. Also, note that there might be more than one instance running of any given application, take chrome for instance, you might have 10 chrome processes running.

Comment: Have you tested it? @Joel

Comment: he's asking to find a specific process by **matching**, not the current one. Your answer does not provide any input for such **matching**.